# Zeros of the Discrete Frourier Transform of a Discrete Probability Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, fourier-transform

Let $\vec{v}\in R^n$ be a probability distribution over a domain of size $n$. I.e., $\vec{v}$ has nonnegative entries that sum up to one.

What can we say about the zeros of $DFT(\vec{v})$, the discrete Fourier transform of $\vec{v}$?

Clearly, for the uniform distribution $\vec{v}=(1/n,...,1/n)$, $DFT(\vec{v})=(1,0,...,0)$. What I am trying to prove or disprove is that for a prime $n$, this is the only case in which $DFT(\vec{v})$ has zeros.

In other words, if $\vec{v}$ is a non-uniform distribution over a domain of size $n$ which is a prime, then $DFT(\vec{v})$ has no zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: Take $n=5$; define $$v_j=\frac1{10}\left(2+2\cos(2\pi j/5)\right)=\frac1{10}\left(2+e^{2\pi ij/5}+e^{2\pi i4j/5}\right)\quad(j=0,1,\dots,4).$$The first form makes it clear that $v_j\ge0$, while the second makes the DFT clear.

Comment: What do you mean an appropriate character? I need v to be a probability distribution, all the entries of it must be real and sum up to one. Below I post an alleged proof showing that the statement is actually true,

Comment: @ShaiHalevi Fixed it...

Comment: Right. Another example is (p,q,0,0,q) where p=1/sqrt(5) and q=2/(5+sqrt(5))